# Listing incomplete college degree on resume after several years of experience?

Tags: resume, education

I've recently begun to re-do my resume and I'm a bit confused on how (or if) to phrase a college degree that was started but not finished.

I was about halfway through the degree when I was offered a great position in the field and "took a break" from school to finish. At this point I've been here for about 2 years, but have an additional 2 years of experience as I was working in school for a total of 4 years industry experience. There would be no gaps in employment if I was to remove the education section.

Right now I have it listed like:

Name Of School -     years attended - Major: Computer Science(Not Completed)

Which was fine initially, but I wonder if it's still necessary now that I have multiple years of experience in the field.

I worry this is a negative as it might show an inability to follow through or complete a long term goal. I'd much rather use the space to list an additional, related project that I have completed.

What's the right move in this situation?

Comment: "*I'd much rather use the space to list an additional, related project that I have completed.*" Regardless of the general answer here, your resume is a personal marketing document. If there's a section there which you know is dead weight or which you an replace with something better it needs to go. But I take it you're also wondering if not listing any academic experience at all may itself be a negative?

Comment: "*2 years of experience as I was working in school*" Just to check, this *is* full-time work? Part-time is usually not fully equivalent when it comes to years of experience.

Answer (score 2):

I would leave your college in your resume .I would state credits passed .I would also tell them about the career offer      that made you decide to leave .Then I would tell them how much you learned in your career .I am assuming that your grades were fine so if you were not poached you would have completed the degree .If you do this on your resume then if you get an interview you can speak from your heart .

Answer (score 1):

> Which was fine initially, but I wonder if it's still necessary now
>   that I have multiple years of experience in the field.

Many positions require a college education.

While you don't have a degree, you do have some education.

If you wish to apply for jobs and want to show that your education plus your experience are a substitute for having a degree, then you should continue to include your education in your resume.

If Computer Science was truly your major, I'm assuming a CS degree might be a requirement for many of the positions you would seek. If that's the case, I'd leave your education listed.

Otherwise, if this education isn't important for the jobs you seek, then you could remove it and not have to talk about why you chose not to finish.